Indexing array with subset of argsorted indices
I'm trying to write a decision tree learner in numpy. For this, the x values need to be sorted once only and after that i should be able to reuse them.
For this, I have a 2d array of features x, of which I obtain the indices to sorted them via i= np.argsort(x, 0). So x[i] returns the sorted columns which is great.
However, for everything after the first split I only require the rows corresponding to a node n. I get stuck on how to chain these indices.
For example, with this data
x = np.array([[1,8,7,4,3,9,0,2,5,6], [7,5,3,8,9,4,6,10,2,1]]).T
i = np.argsort(x, 0)
n = np.nonzero(x[:, 0] < 6)[0] 

I want to have x[n] but where the columns are sorted.
x[i[n], np.arange(2)] works for the first column (on which the mask n is based), but the second column contains the wrong data.
Taking x[n] first changes the shape after which I can't index it with the i array anymore.
I'm kinda lost here, would appreciate any help.

If I've understood your question right, you can do:
print(x[i][n, :, 0])

Prints:
[[0 6]
 [3 9]
 [4 8]
 [6 1]
 [7 4]
 [8 3]]


This seems to work, thank you! Could you give an explanation as to why it works or reference the documentation so I can learn this pattern for future use?

@NotProbable x[i] return array of shape (10, 2, 2) - that means 10 2x2 matrices. These 2x2 matrices means: row 0 is sorted by values in column x[0] and row 1 is sorted by values in column x[1]. So we filter n these 2x2 matrices and get column 0 from each matrix.

In testing again, this solution does not work for me. I asked a new question to clarify the problem I'm having here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78434965/numpy-index-argsorted-with-integer-array-while-retaining-sorting-order
