Numpy index argsorted with integer array while retaining sorting order
I have an array x and the result of argsorting it i. I need to sort x (and y, irrelevant here) according to i hundreds of times. It is therefore not doable to sort the data twice, everything needs to be achieved via the initial sorting i.
If I take x[i] it returns the sorted x as expected. However, I now only want to use certain rows of x via n. So x[n] returns the values of x as expected.
My problem is that I need to sort these x[n] via i (and will have to do the same for y[n].
# Example data
x = np.array([14, 15,  9,  6, 19, 18,  4, 11, 10,  0])
i = np.argsort(x)
n = np.array([2, 5, 7, 8])

#x[n] -> array([ 9, 18, 11, 10])

Desired output: index_sort(x, n, i) = array([ 9, 10, 11, 18])
Some simple (failed) attempts:
x[n][i] -> Indexing error, as x is now too small. 
x[i[n]] -> array([ 6, 11, 15, 18]),  Is sorted, but contains the wrong data 
x[i][n] -> Same
For more context: I'm creating a specific type of decision tree model. For each layer of the tree I need the above operation a different n. Sorting becomes prohibitively expensive and even checking for set membership via np.isin might be too slow as well already. My intuition (though perhaps wrong) says it should be possible to achieve this via indexing only, without ever having to sort or check for set membership.
For all these layers x and i remain the same, but a different n is used each time.

Do you mean print(np.sort(x[n])) ?

Can't you just sort x[n]?  No need to use i

Apologies, I added clarification: I need to sort other arrays according to i and n too, so direct sorting of x won't work. Plus, this procedure repeats hundreds of times and would be the main bottleneck of the code.

Think about these indices in detail.  Don't randomly try things hoping something magical will work. i indexes x, permuting all elements. n also indexes x, selecting a subset of values (maybe even duplicates?). They are unrelated.  But, what does argsort(i) look like? I think that can be used to 'unsort' x[i].

@hpaulj I actually use this argsort(i) in a different bit later on to undo the sorting via np.argsort(i)[n] to reconstruct the original indices each of each of the x_i. I just can't see on how to actually obtain the sorting there.

In [263]: x = np.array([14, 15,  9,  6, 19, 18,  4, 11, 10,  0])
     ...: i = np.argsort(x)
     ...: n = np.array([2, 5, 7, 8])

i and n do different, and unrelated indexing operations.  Both make copies (not views), which don't retain any information on the original x:
In [264]: x[i]
Out[264]: array([ 0,  4,  6,  9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19])

In [265]: x[n]
Out[265]: array([ 9, 18, 11, 10])

Let's try working with a boolean mask:
In [266]: m = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=bool)    
In [267]: m[n] = True; m
Out[267]: 
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True,
       False])

It selects elements from x same as n (though it won't handle duplicates the same):
In [268]: x[m]
Out[268]: array([ 9, 18, 11, 10])

Now try applying the sort to m:
In [269]: mi = m[i]; m
Out[269]: 
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True,
       False])

It does select the desired elements from the sorted x[i]:
In [270]: x[i][mi]
Out[270]: array([ 9, 10, 11, 18])

We could also convert that boolean mask back to indices:
In [272]: ni = np.nonzero(mi)[0]; ni
Out[272]: array([3, 4, 5, 8], dtype=int64)
In [273]: x[i][ni]
Out[273]: array([ 9, 10, 11, 18])


Trying to sort x[n] solely based on i wouldn't be more efficient.
i gives you the final array and the positions in x from which to fetch the values to have the sorted order.
This means that you cannot index i with n.
I you really want to sort x[n] based on i you would need to identify the positions of i that match n, then reorder based on that:
out = x[n][np.argsort(i[np.isin(i, n)])]
# array([ 9, 10, 11, 18])

The most efficient is most likely to sort x[n]:
out = np.sort(x[n])

Or, to repeat the process, first index, then argsort and you can reuse i:
i = np.argsort(x[n])
# array([0, 3, 2, 1])

out = x[n][i]
# array([ 9, 10, 11, 18])


Thank you for your solution. While it works, it still requires sorting twice. Theoretically, there should be no need for this given that all the orderings are the same and that is the solution I'm looking for.

@NotProbable your exact use case is unclear, but if you want to reuse the same n, then the best approach is i = np.argsort(x[n]) ; x[n][i], which only sorts once. Please give a minimal example of your real use case (show us what is variable/reused).

I added more context for the specific usecase. The main issue is that x is large and constant, but n will change all the time.

@NotProbable then, I'm sorry but this is not possible, you'll have either to sort the slice (O(k*logk) complexity with k the size of the slice) or to test membership (O(n) complexity with n the size of x). Whether one or the other is better depends on n and k.

It feels like this is an XY Problem. Anyway here is a solution with np.in1d:
x[i[np.in1d(i, n)]]

array([ 9, 10, 11, 18])


Note that the goal is to get n in the order of i. thats what i[np.in1d(i, n)] does

Doesn't np.in1d use sorting internally? I'm now wondering if it's possible to achieve the same results as in1d via indexing somehow

@NotProbable no, it does not. It uses membership comparison. ie it only outputs true if a value is within another set otherwise false. There is no sorting involved.
